# Windows Store app side loading

Tags: windows-store-apps, sideloading

I need to sideload my Windows store app. What are the changes needed to be done into my app? Is the Signing of the package is a must, given that am referencing third party assemblies that are not signed. Should I create a certificate? I kind of know some titles but have no idea about how to do them, the right order or what else am I missing.

Appreciate if anybody has a good walk-through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the useful stuff for you to setup and tryout sideloading of Windows 8 applications

[Document](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CD4QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.technet.com%2Fcfs-filesystemfile.ashx%2F__key%2Fcommunityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles%2F00-00-00-62-43-download%2F5165.itcamp.win8.sideloading.LabManual.docx&ei=-kAwUovmLK6S0QW9ioCYCQ&usg=AFQjCNHzpvBhG67sX2VzUF_vsxX-C8RNHQ&sig2=HCiAIXPwqMPwxhg21gY8aw&bvm=bv.51773540,d.d2k&cad=rja), [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/jj874388.aspx?ocid=wc-nl-insider)